# How to make a upload image functionality in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, file-upload, upload

I m trying to create a upload image page. However I want to it implementend in a way that I want the uploaded file to be saved in the directory of assest in my angular project folder. In that way I can store only the url of the image in my DB. SO I want to save this file without using a backend. I dont want to save the files in my back end. Is this possible or is there another way to upload files without using a back end?

Comment: You would need a Server Side language like PHP or nodejs for even saving the file to your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to save the file in a folder without your server running.

Read

- [how to upload image in node js](https://datainflow.com/upload-image-node-js/)
- [Upload Files Or Images To Server Using Node.js](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-files-or-images-to-server-using-node-js/)
- [File uploads using Node.js](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/file-uploads-using-node-js/)

And visit

- [Imgur](https://api.imgur.com)
- [Uploapfiles.io](https://uploadfiles.io/)
- [files.fm](https://files.fm/)

With these services you can save files without back-end